# Should I mark my derived class destructors virtual/override?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, destructor

The C++ core guidelines contain the [following advice](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final) regarding the `virtual`, `override` and `final` specifiers, specifically relating to derived class destructors:

> If a base class destructor is declared virtual, one should avoid declaring derived class destructors virtual or override. Some code base and tools might insist on override for destructors, but that is not the recommendation of these guidelines.

Sure enough, `clang-tidy` is one of those tools that goes against the recommendation.
If I do not specify either `virtual` or `override`, running `clang-tidy` emits the following warning:

```
warning: annotate this function with 'override' or (rarely) 'final' [modernize-use-override]
```

or, if specified just as `virtual`:

```
warning: prefer using 'override' or (rarely) 'final' instead of 'virtual' [modernize-use-override]
```

#### My question

Given that specifying `override`, in particular, has the advantage of (at least) ensuing you have correctly specified the base class destructor as `virtual`, my question boils down to the following specific parts:

1. What, if any, are the arguments in favour of *not* specifying `virtual` or `override` on derived class destructors?
2. In your opinion, should I lean more towards the `clang-tidy` advice, or towards the C++ core guidelines advice?

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1000

Comment: This is the question that is on everyone's lips, in everyone's minds and (sometimes) in everyone's bedrooms.

Comment: This is an excellent question, but off-topic here on SO I think: this is opinion-based. You should join the discussion on github directly.

Comment: @YSC 1. isn't opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What, if any, are the arguments in favour of not specifying ... `override` on derived class destructors?

There are non-conformant compilers that fail to compile when destructor is specified with `override`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfzxhe2a.aspx.

1. What, if any, are the arguments in favour of not specifying `virtual` ... on derived class destructors [when it is virtual implicitly]?

Less code is better. You save 7 characters worth by not using redundant `virtual`.

- Counter argument: 7 characters is not much of a saving.

There might be a design decision to make a previously virtual destructor non-virtual for a base class and all of its children. If this guideline (of not specifying redundant `virtual`) is strictly followed, then only the base needs to be modified. Otherwise each child in the hierarchy must be modified (or at least checked whether they specify `virtual` separately).

- Counter argument: This might be a completely hypothetical situation. Certainly quite rare.

---

2. In your opinion, should I lean more towards the clang-tidy advice, or towards the C++ core guidelines advice?

The only argument that has significant weight in my opinion is the non-conformance of old Visual Studio compilers, and thus I would err on the side of not using `override` on destructors. Otherwise it matters very little and you can follow whichever guideline you prefer, or don't even bother following either - consistency isn't important when the subject at hand makes no difference.